# Filter release label only for a specific namespace label

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating

I have a grafana instance that monitors certain releases deployed in a namespace. The namespace is hardcoded in my queries for graphs like

```
jenkins_health_check_score{namespace="build",release="$release"}
```

And I want to filter based on only the variable `release`

The problem right now is that grafana will list the release names deployed in ALL namespaces in the filter. But I want it to list only the releases deployed in the `build` namespace.

My current config looks like

[image]

I tried doing something like

```
label_values(release)
label_values(namespace="build")
```

But that does not work.

I get the error

```
Template variables could not be initialized: 2:13: parse error: could not parse remaining input "(release)\nlabel"...
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Query: query_result(jenkins_health_check_score{namespace="build"})
Regex: /release="([^"]+)"/
```

Comment: This does not work. `jenkins_health_check_score{namespace="build",release="$release"}` is the Metrics query of my graph. So I cant use it in my variable query unfortunately.